# Using ReflectionClass when Instantiating object within static function doesn't seem to work PHP 5.6

Tags: php, prestashop, php-5.6

Using PHP5.6 (7.0 doesn't seem to have the same result)

The code I'm calling is to instantiate an object from a static function within that class.

```
class SomeClass extends ObjectModel
{ 
  public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'roja45_productrental_rental',
    'primary' => 'id_roja45_product_rental',
    'multilang' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        'id_customer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
    ),
  );

  public $id_customer;

  public static function getInstance() {
    $instance = new SomeClass();
    return $instance
  }
}
```

The exception itself is generated by Prestsahop but what Prestashop does is this:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);

if (!$reflection->hasProperty('definition')) {
    return false;
}
```

property 'definition' being a static variable in the class.

When you instantiate the class from a non-static function there's no problem, but from the example scenario above, ReflectionClass doesn't return anything and Prestashop generates an error.

There's something about PHP5.6 that I clearly don't understand.

How should I be instantiating that $instance variable so ReflectionClass works as it should?

Thanks all

Comment: That's weird. Object instantiation through static method works just fine for me on php5.6 (aside from the missing `;` at `return $instance`).

Comment: Works fine with 5.6.29: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/150e9b50615e2578d6ac45b5daa28a2844f3bf41

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: No error message per se, the reflection class is returned is just returns false when you call $reflection->hasProperty('definition') when it gets called similar to the example above.  When hasProperty is called from a non-static method it returns true.

Comment: I updated that php sanbox script to make it a bit more accurate, as there are other things going on that just the code I posted: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ebadcde709cb8bc2d8e6096a4462284dfbd72d2  as with the previous one though, it still works in the sandbox tested, it just doesn't work in the main code.

Comment: I can only suggest to debug it. Evidently the problem is not the one stated in the question. Check if the `$class` variable has correct value. I have updated your code to show an example of how it may result with an error http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2669d01d1b68c45a58df138c7ed7e3ef391a6f40 by changing `$class_name = get_class($this);` to `$class_name = __CLASS__;`

Comment: Debugging it got me this far, how would you suggest I debug the reflection class, that's PHP core code and the debugger won't step into it.  Like I said, the code works when calling it from a non-static function, not when calling it from a static function, so the class code doesn't change, and therefore the class name is the same in both instances.  The problem, again, is that when I'm using php 5.6, the function call $hasProperty returns false when checking for the static definition property, when I try to instantiate the class from a static method on that class.